# Create a hash of a mesh in Blender python

Tags: python, hash, blender, mesh

How do I create a hash from mesh data (`mesh.toString` ?).
So identical meshes will generate the same hash.

How can this be done in python?

Comment: `import hashlib` and pick your choice.

Comment: see also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/286010/bpy-detect-modified-mesh-data-vertices-edges-loops-or-polygons-for-cachin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to tzamans comment I was able to generate with hashlib:

```
hash = hashlib.sha224( str(plain_verts).strip('[]').encode('utf-8') ).hexdigest()
```